# Bootstrap 4: How to show one collapsible item and hide others?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have some collapsible menus and I want to hide others when one clicked. Please note I want to completely hide them, not collapse them. It's different from accordion behavior.

I used accordion code and added the following function:

```
$('#bottomNavBar .collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    // do something…
    var me = e.target;
    $('#bottomNavBar [aria-expanded="false"]').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(me)) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the item which has been clicked to expand is also hides because its `aria-expanded` is false (however its sub-menus appears). I didn't want to use `shown.bs.collapse` event because of my visual plans. I tried to compare each item with the calling object but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This function solved my problem, I just need `click` event.

```
$('#bottomNavBar [aria-expanded="false"]').on('click', function (e) {
    // do something…
    var me = this;
    $('#bottomNavBar [aria-expanded="false"]').each(function () {
        if (this != me) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```